# Create a hierarchy with multiple levels based on two columns of data

Tags: excel, vba, dax, powerpivot

I have a list of all employees in my group/company.  They are listed by Employee ID and Supervisor ID.  I want to make a pivot table that is expandable so I can sum data up and down between levels.  This data is centered around hours and dollars spent on a monthly basis.

I believe if I used PowerPivot and used the hierarchy feature this is doable.  The issue is getting the raw data into a format that will work properly.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

Data:

```
ID      SupID
A1000   B1000
A1111   B1000
A1234   A1000
A2222   C1000
B1000   D2391
C1000   B1000
D2391
```

Would turn data into

```
ID      Lvl1Sup  Lvl2Sup  Lvl3Sup
D2391           
B1000   D2391       
A1000   D2391    B1000  
A1111   D2391    B1000  
A2222   D2391    B1000    C1000
```

Does anyone have a VBA macro that would do this?  Possibly down to a 7th level?  Am I headed in the right direction with the PowerPivot idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you further explain how you're getting this second table? Why does `D2391` have its own line?

Comment: Sorry.  D2391 would be the highest lvl employee.  Added a row to show that.  'ID' in the second table is the employee ID.  Because A2222 is at the 4th level of an org chart, he/she has a level 1 supervisor, a level 2 supervisor, and a lvl 3 supervisor.  I cant really think of another way of organizing the data that would allow me to dig down levels of employees.

Comment: I'm sorry but it it is still unclear *how* you're getting this second table result. Why is `D2391` in the ID column then in Lvl1Sup column for the other rows? Where is `A1234` in the second table? There are too many questions here for me (or anyone else, it looks like) to help you. Specifics are key.

Comment: Example:  D2391 is a VP and has no supervisor.  He is at the top.  B1000 is a Director who reports to D2391 which is shown in the first table ID->B1000, SupID->D2391.  A1000 is a program manger and reports to B1000.  This is shown in the first table ID->A1000, SupID->B1000.  To translate that to the second table for Employee A1000.  A1000's highest level supervisor is D2319 so in column lvl1Sup it is D2319.  A1000's second highest level supervisor is B1000 so B1000 is in column lvl2Sup.  I basically need to map the chain of command from the top to the bottom of the organization.

Comment: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Comment: Wow that looks like the exact thing I need. Appreciate the time you all took to read and help me out. Interesting this link didn’t pop up when I was researching.